Github Google Colab Repository Access
I have a .ipynb file I've written in Google Colab that I would like to put in a folder in a public GitHub repository titled "Portfolio." When I save a copy of the file from Google Colab to the repository I can open the file on another computer without being logged in no problem. If, after copying the file from Colab, I move the file into the sub folder within the Portfolio repository I am no longer able to access if not logged in to GitHub/Google and I get a message saying that the notebook wasn't found. How do I fix this?
To be clear for some reason I'm unable to copy the file from Colab directly into the subfolder. I have to copy it into the repository and then change the path manually within GitHub. I assume this is where the problem is coming from.
